# Passing string array to c programming from C#

Tags: c#, c

I am calling unmanaged C programming code from C# .Net managed code. But I am unable to pass string array as a parameter to function from .Net
Function in C:

```
dllmain(const int argc, const char *argv[]){}
```

Please help me, how I can call this function from C Sharp.Net

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attributes to the parameter `argv` when declaring the function in .net:

```
[In][MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
```

You should also add the `CharSet=CharSet.Unicode` property to the DllImport attribute applied to the external function.

Comment: Hi,
    Your way of connecting unmanaged code with managed code is working fine but when I am passing arguments by ref string, then it's not working. Data is changed automatically in the arguments. Please help me.


Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do that:

C# code:

1. Declare C function you want call from C#

   ```
   [DllImport("<DLL_File_Name>.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "dllmain", ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void dllmain(ref string str1);
   ```
2. Define the string

   ```
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
       public string str1;
   ```
3. Call the C function from C# code

   ```
       dllmain(ref str1);
   ```

C Code:

1. Function prototype

   ```
   __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall dllmain(char *str1);
   ```
2. Function definition

   ```
   void__stdcall dllmain(char *str1)
   {
       :
   }
   ```

Hope this will be helpful for you. :-)

Comment: the question was regarding a string array, not just one string